# Find all values in column B associated with values in column A in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, associated-sorting

I have a data frame in R that looks like this:

```
bin   Family    Genus 
 1     blue     flower     
 1     green    moss   
 1     blue     tree  
 2     red      bird   
 2     red      lizard
```

It is possible to have the same bin multiple times, and the associated families/genera may not be unique to one bin. I am looking to identify all families associated with each bin, and how many times each family is associated with each bin. I will repeat the test for genus.
I am ultimately trying to identify if there is variation in the names associated with each bin so I can then choose the most common name for each bin and assign that bin just one name. My data frame is quite large with thousands of bins.

Comment: maybe you want `with(df, table(bin, family))`?

Comment: That definitely works, thanks for your reply! With my data the result is an enormous table (approx. 8000 bins by hundreds of families) that is difficult to extract information from by eye. Can you suggest a way to remove all bins from the table that don't have multiple families associated with it? That would narrow it down quite a bit.

Comment: You can assign that result to an object and subset it (like a matrix, since it is 2-dimensional). `tab = with(df, table(bin, family))`, then `tab[rowSums(tab) > 1, ]`.

Comment: @Gregor This isn't exactly what I am looking for as it is not removing bins with only one family. This might be because the one family has many records. eg. bin 1 has 250 records in family blue, 0 records in all other families

Comment: Okay, how about `tab[rowSums(tab != 0) > 1, ]`. You can subset it any way you like.